# No puedo eliminar valores nulos con Series.dropna (pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tafe.csv')

df['LengthofService'].isnull().sum()
```

Output:

```
106
```

Tengo 106 valores nulos en esta columna, los quiero eliminar:

```
df['LengthofService'].dropna(inplace=True)
df['LengthofService'].isnull().sum()
```

Output:

```
106
```

Sin embargo, si hago directamente:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df['LengthofService'].isnull().sum()
```

Output:

```
0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El parámetro `inplace` en las operaciones de `Pandas` solo funciona con los objetos `DataFrame`. Si quieres cambiar solo una columna de un `DataFrame` debes hacerlo reasignando la columna:

```
df['LengthofService'] = df['LengthofService'].dropna()
```

Mi recomendación, es que no uses el parámetro `inplace` en las operaciones, ya que es bastante difuso y puede darte problemas. De hecho `Pandas` lleva intentando quitarlo bastante tiempo, y posiblemente desaparezca en próximas versiones. Esto lo puedes ver en esta [*issue* en Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529)